# call to function failed when when 0 OR NULL passed to shared pointer(shared_ptr OR unique_ptr) indirectly via template

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
#include<iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;
class Linux
{
};
int f1(std::shared_ptr<Linux> spw) // call these only when
{
  //do something
  return 0;
}
double f2(std::unique_ptr<Linux> upw) // the appropriate
{
  //do something
  return 0.0;
}
bool f3(Linux* pw) // mutex is locked
{

return 0;
}

std::mutex f1m, f2m, f3m; // mutexes for f1, f2, and f3
using MuxtexGuard = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>;

void lockAndCallF1()
{
        MuxtexGuard g(f1m); // lock mutex for f1
        auto result = f1(static_cast<int>(0)); // pass 0 as null ptr to f1
        cout<< result<<endl;
}

void lockAndCallF2()
{
        MuxtexGuard g(f2m); // lock mutex for f2
        auto result = f2(static_cast<int>(NULL)); // pass NULL as null ptr to f2
        cout<< result<<endl;
}
void lockAndCallF3()
{
        MuxtexGuard g(f3m); // lock mutex for f2
        auto result = f3(nullptr);// pass nullptr as null ptr to f3 
        cout<< result<<endl;
} // unlock mutex
int main()
{
        lockAndCallF1();
        lockAndCallF2();
        lockAndCallF3();
        return 0;
}
```

Above program compile and executed successfully but lockAndCallF1, lockAndCallF2 & lockAndCallF3 have redundant code. So it can be generalized with template. I have written template function `lockAndCall` instead of multiple definition `lockAndCallF1, lockAndCallF2 & lockAndCallF3` for redundant code.

Code is re-factored as below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;
class Linux
{
};
int f1(std::shared_ptr<Linux> spw) // call these only when
{
  //do something
  return 0;
}
double f2(std::unique_ptr<Linux> upw) // the appropriate
{
  //do something
  return 0.0;
}
bool f3(Linux* pw) // mutex is locked
{

return 0;
}

std::mutex f1m, f2m, f3m; // mutexes for f1, f2, and f3
using MuxtexGuard = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>;

template<typename FuncType, typename MuxType, typename PtrType>
auto lockAndCall(FuncType func, MuxType& mutex, PtrType ptr) -> decltype(func(ptr))
//decltype(auto) lockAndCall(FuncType func, MuxType& mutex, PtrType ptr)
{
        MuxtexGuard g(mutex);
        return func(ptr);
}
int main()
{
        auto result1 = lockAndCall(f1, f1m, 0); //compilation failed 
        //do something
        auto result2 = lockAndCall(f2, f2m, NULL); //compilation failed
        //do something
        auto result3 = lockAndCall(f3, f3m, nullptr);
        //do something
        return 0;
}
```

compilation failed with below error

```
$ g++ nullptr.cpp  --std=c++11
nullptr.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
nullptr.cpp:39:49: error: no matching function for call to ‘lockAndCall(double (&)(std::unique_ptr<Linux>), std::mutex&, NULL)’
         auto result2 = lockAndCall(f2, f2m, NULL); //compilation failed
                                                 ^
nullptr.cpp:39:49: note: candidate is:
nullptr.cpp:29:6: note: template<class FuncType, class MuxType, class PtrType> decltype (func(ptr)) lockAndCall(FuncType, MuxType&, PtrType)
 auto lockAndCall(FuncType func, MuxType& mutex, PtrType ptr) -> decltype(func(ptr))
      ^
nullptr.cpp:29:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
nullptr.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class FuncType, class MuxType, class PtrType> decltype (func(ptr)) lockAndCall(FuncType, MuxType&, PtrType) [with FuncType = double (*)(std::unique_ptr<Linux>); MuxType = std::mutex; PtrType = long int]’:
nullptr.cpp:39:49:   required from here
nullptr.cpp:29:82: error: could not convert ‘ptr’ from ‘long int’ to ‘std::unique_ptr<Linux>’
 auto lockAndCall(FuncType func, MuxType& mutex, PtrType ptr) -> decltype(func(ptr))
```

**Question1.** Why lockAndCall call is failed when parameter's 0 OR Null f1(std::shared_ptr spw) and f2(std::unique_ptr upw) respectively and function call `f1(static_cast<int>(0));` and `auto result = f2(static_cast<int>(NULL));` successfully called with 0 and NULL?

**Question2** what will be the type of FuncType after lockAndCall function deduction? FuncType is type of function pointer or std::function?

Comment: Can you provide a *minimal* reproducing sample?

Comment: It's an interesting question, but please [edit] your question with the smallest program reproducing the problem.

Comment: Your question is a mess, a lot of details not related and is not clear what you are asking

Comment: why anonymous downward the question? do you have any suggestion? or it is duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your question is for function declared as:

```
int f1(std::shared_ptr<Linux> spw);
```

why following code compiles:

```
f1(static_cast<int>(0));
```

but following does not:

```
template<typename FuncType, typename MuxType, typename PtrType>
auto lockAndCall(FuncType func, MuxType& mutex, PtrType ptr) -> decltype(func(ptr))
{
        MuxtexGuard g(mutex);
        return func(ptr);
}

lockAndCall( f1, f1m, 0);
```

Reason is `std::shared_ptr` has non explicit constructor for `nullptr` and integer constant of value 0 can be implicitly converted to `nullptr`. When you call `f1` indirectly, through template function  - parameter is not constant expression with value 0 so it cannot be converted to `nullptr`. Note what value you have in that parameter at runtime does not matter, this resolved at compilation time, when data type of expressions are evaluated.

As for `NULL` [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) says:

> The macro NULL is an implementation-defined null pointer constant, which may be an integral constant expression prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t (for C++11)
>
> Possible implementation

```
 #define NULL 0
 //since C++11
 #define NULL nullptr
```

looks like your implementation has `NULL` defined as literal 0, not `nullptr`

To solve the issue pass `nullptr` explicitly, not 0 or `NULL` or even better default constructed `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`:

```
lockAndCall( f1, f1m, std::shared_ptr<Linux>{} );
```

Comment: I love anonymous downvoters

Comment: Hi Slava, Thank you for answer, Do you mean NULL is defined as nullptr in c++11/14?

Comment: @Ajayyadav it can be defined as integer 0 or `nullptr` in either one. Anyway your code should not depend on that.

Comment: ok, one more question, just to confirm my understanding with your answer, it will be similar scenario void lockAndCallF1()
{
        MuxtexGuard g(f1m); // lock mutex for f1
        int i =0;
        auto result = f1(i); // pass 0 as null ptr to f1
        cout<< result<<endl;
} its compilation also failed necadmin@necadmin-HP-ProBook-430-G1:~/c++$ g++ nullptr.cpp  --std=c++11
nullptr.cpp: In function ‘void lockAndCallF1()’:
nullptr.cpp:32:20: error: could not convert ‘i’ from ‘int’ to ‘std::shared_ptr<Linux>’
  auto result = f1(i); ----> failed because i is integer instead of literal

Comment: @Ajayyadav yes, it has to be compile time constant, if you add `constexpr` or `const` to `int` it should compile again

Comment: @black why? this is what cppreference.com says.

Comment: Hi Slava, constexpr and const int does not work                                nullptr.cpp: In function ‘void lockAndCallF1()’:
nullptr.cpp:32:20: error: could not convert ‘i’ from ‘const int’ to ‘std::shared_ptr<Linux>’

Comment: Sorry I wanted to rather say it is unlikely to be defined as nullptr because of backward compatibility.

Comment: @Ajayyadav yes does not compile for me either. Looks like I do not understand something and strange, there is no such question on stack, at least I cannot fine one

Comment: @Ajayyadav created this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515544/conversion-from-int-to-nullptr why const/constexpr int does not work

Comment: @ Slava thanks for your time

Comment: Hi Slava, what is the type deducted for FuncType, also please answer the second question? Does its type std::function?

Comment: @Ajayyadav no it is not `std::function`