# Conversion from integral constant expression to null-pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, null, c++14

Consider following code:

```
#include <memory>

void f( std::shared_ptr<int> ) {}

int main()
{
    f( 0 );               // compiles fine in gcc and clang
    f( 1 - 1 );           // compiles fine in gcc, fails in clang
    constexpr int i = 0;
    f( i );               // fails to compile in gcc and clang
    f( i - 0 );           // compiles fine in gcc, fails in clang
}
```

why only `f( i )` fails to compile, though `i` should be evaluated as compile time constant with value 0?

PS checked with g++ v 5.1.0, it accepts all variants except `f(i);` in both c++11 and c++14 mode
PPS checked with clang 3.7, it rejects all variants except literal 0 in both c++11 and c++14 mode

Comment: Compiler knows 0 is "valid" pointer (NULL) but otherwise not. I don't think any of this is correct code, even though some of it works.

Comment: I'm not sure `nullptr` is involved in this question at all; it's about conversion from `int` to `void *`.

Comment: @Tommy changed to `std::shared_ptr` to be about `nullptr` for sure

Comment: Note this could be generalized more [see the live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jDAD3s3T9bsNVnhn) and we can see that clang accepts the more general example in C++03 as does gcc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a gcc bug. [Defect report 903: Value-dependent integral null pointer constants](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#903)  which is a defect report against C++11(*it has CD3 status*),  makes it so that only an integer literal `0` is considered a null pointer constant.

It changed section `4.10` [conv.ptr] paragraph `1` amongst other changes from:

> A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19 [expr.const]) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero [...]

to:

> A null pointer constant is an integer literal (2.14.2 [lex.icon]) with value zero [...]

This is listed as an incompatibility against C++03, from section `C.2.2` Clause 4: standard conversions *[diff.cpp03.conv]* which says:

> **Change:** Only literals are integer null pointer constants
>  
>   **Rationale:** Removing surprising interactions with templates and
>   constant expressions
>   **Effect on original feature:** Valid C++ 2003 code may fail to compile or
>   produce different results in this International Standard, as the
>   following example illustrates:
>
> ```
> void f(void *); // #1
> void f(...); // #2
> template<int N> void g() {
>   f(0*N); // calls #2; used to call #1
> }
> ```

The following gcc bug report [[C++11] [DR 903] zero-valued integer constant expression should prefer conversion to pointer](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52145) shows that the gcc team originally thought this was a C++17 change but later changed it to be in effect in C++11.

We can see in the head revision of gcc(*6.0*) this is fixed (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bv11uodgGHlloJRE)*) and produces a diagnostic for all the cases clang does:

```
error: could not convert '(1 - 1)' from 'int' to 'std::shared_ptr<int>'
 f( 1 - 1 );           // compiles fine in gcc, fails in clang
    ~~^~~

error: could not convert 'i' from 'const int' to 'std::shared_ptr<int>'
 f( i );               // fails to compile in gcc and clang
      ^

error: could not convert '(0 - 0)' from 'int' to 'std::shared_ptr<int>'
 f( i - 0 );           // compiles fine in gcc, fails in clang
    ~~^~~
```

Comment: Good find, particularily the rationale against arbitrary constant expressions.

Answer (score 6):

Because a *null pointer constant* is defined not just as a compile-time integral constant with value 0, but as an integer **literal** with value zero (or as a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`, of course). C++14 (N4140), 4.10/1.

So actually, only the first line `f(0)` should compile, all the other ones should provoke at least a diagnostic message from a conforming compiler.

Comment: g++ does not provide any diagnostics even in -pedantic mode

Comment: @Slava Would technically be worth a bug report, then, if there's not one already.

Comment: N3242 says "A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression" - do you have a link for C++14 which says **literal**?

Comment: Never mind, N3797 says **literal** just as you quoted.  Interesting change from C++11 (and C) to C++14.

Comment: @MartinBonner so it means it should compile fine in c++11 mode?

Comment: @Slava It would seem so.

Comment: so it is still unclear why in c++11 mode only `f(i)` fails to compile

Comment: @Angew It's a post-C++11 DR that's intended to apply to C++11, so it's supposed to be rejected in C++11 mode too. That's also why N4140 lists it as an incompatibility with C++03 rather than with C++11 ([diff.cpp03.conv]).